# Uri returned after ACTION_GET_CONTENT from gallery is not working in setImageURI() of ImageView

Tags: android, imageview, uri

I am fetching Uri of a image from gallery using

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setType("image/*");  
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Picture"), requestCode);
```

and trying to display the image by

```
imageView.setImageURI(uri);
```

here, uri is Uri of  the image received in onActivityResult by intent.getData().

but no image is being displayed. Also, for

```
File file=new File( uri.getPath() );
```

file.exists() is returning false.

Comment: are you checking the uri value.. log and check.. paste the uri here

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that you getting the Uri but from that uri you have to create Bitmap to show in your Imageview. There are various mechanism to do the same one among them is this code.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setType("image/*");  
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);  
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose Picture"), 1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    if(resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED)
    {
        // action cancelled
    }
    if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri selectedimg = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageBitmap(MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedimg));
    }
}
```

Comment: `MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

***Launch the Gallery Image Chooser***

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
// Show only images, no videos or anything else
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
// Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

***PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST is the request code defined as an instance variable.***

```
private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
```

***Show Up the Selected Image in the Activity/Fragment***

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));

            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

***Your layout will need to have an ImageView like this:***

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />
```