# How to invoke the default file chooser picker in Android?

Tags: android, file-upload, filechooser

If you go to [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) from your Android device, click on Upload an Image and then on `Touch here to select your images`, the Android prompts you with a `Choose file for upload` with few options. The good thing about this picker is that even if there is no camera as an option (for older phones) you can start the camera from the Gallery application, take a picture and eventually select it from the gallery to be uploaded.

That works also for any file `<input>` on any website.

So my question is: how can I invoke that file picker and eventually get the path to the selected image in native Java app?

If possible I would like to filter it so it will prompt only for images and not audio files and I don't want to install any file managers since it's doable within the browser. It's hard to believe that is available only for the Browser.

I don't want to implement my own file browser or list the camera's folder within my app. I'm also just starting with Android so a complete example to get eventually the file path or an image would be awesome.

Comment: Are you asking for an HTML5 Web app (in a place where you don't want to use `<input>`), or for a native Java app?

Comment: @CommonsWare Native Java app... in HTML5 it's obvious.. just use the `<input type="file">`

Comment: @CommonsWare maybe the tag file-upload is misleading, but I didn't know what to add ;) Feel free to edit as needed..

Comment: **Careful about assumptions** on many (I dare say most at present) android devices, your example does not result in an opportunity to pick a *file* but rather only in opportunities to pick an application to provide something such as an *image*.  Only if the user has installed a file manager app, or the device atypically came with one, or you have some potential recently featureful android build will this get you the ability to actually pick a *file*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the chooser that comes up, `<input>` would appear to be requesting an `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` activity, with a MIME type of `*/*`.

> If possible I would like to filter it so it will prompt only for images and not audio files

Use a MIME type of `image/*`.

> I'm also just starting with Android so a complete example to get eventually the file path or an image would be awesome.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10274699/115145

Comment: @Lipis: BTW, it dawned on me that I have a more complete example of `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` here: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/Content

Comment: Pretty straight forward.. Nice one.. I might use it as well to get an image directly from a Camera.

Comment: It worked like a glove..!! I also managed to go all the way and upload it after going through this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3801665/8418

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to get multiple files from that chooser? You can definitely choose many files from the Gallery application.. but is it possible to ask for more than file.. or it has to be done the either way around.. choose files and then share on your app..?

Comment: @Lipis: "Do you know if it's possible to get multiple files from that chooser?" -- no, only one. "choose files and then share on your app" -- that direction uses `ACTION_SEND` (one) or `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE` (more than one).